# Create "Permalink" functionality in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

Recently i am working with codeigniter. I need to create a permalink functionality just like as wordpress. Can anyone suggest me a way that, how i can implement this in codeigniter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you give more details about what you want to do.
In my understanding you want to create something like this?

```
http://example.com/2012/post-name/
```

1) You must have a mod_rewrite.
2) Use the controller or model but will advice to use Controller

Controller:

```
    public function something(string name, int year){
     //some code
   }
```

This will be translated to

```
http://www.example.com/something/name/year
```

Hope this helps or you can paste your code so I can explain further.

Comment: Thank you, for replying. I need to create a page, e.g a admin added "about us" page then the permalink of that page should be "`http://domain.com/about-us`"

Answer (score 0):

So create the page: admin.php

Then in the controller:

```
public function about-us(){
 $this->view->load('about-us');
}
```

When you run the page is will be: `http://domain.com/about-us`. about-us is the function in the controller.

Comment: I have created a page module where the admin can add the pages as much he can. But the issue is to display that pages with the permalink which is defined by the admin just like the **wordpress page**. I think now it is cleared to you.

Comment: You can't have `'-'` in a function name.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to remove the spaces and replace with a hyphen?

```
$slug = 'this is a bad slug';
$fixed_slug = str_replace(' ', '-', $slug);
# uncomment next line to see result
# echo $fixed_slug;
```

If you want to make that a method, no worries:

```
public function fix_slug($slug){
    $fixed_slug = str_replace(' ', '-', $slug);
    return $fixed_slug;
}
```

You can obviously do more in that method, or abstract it to use with other text you want altered.